# NSDateFormatter ISO8601 NSString do NSdate conversion

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter, iso8601

i have a problem to convert string date (maybe ISO 8601) to NSDate..

```
NSString *testDate = @"2016-01-27T18:28:53.344+01:00";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZZZZZ"];

NSLog(@"_date_: %@",[formatter dateFromString:testDate]);
NSLog(@"_now_date: %@",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

NSLog return:
`_date_:(null)
_now_date: 2016-02-03T22:36:46.046+01:00`

What is the right time format ? if log current date the format maybe appear correct but i can't get NSDate from string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fractional second in your date string. Fractional seconds are designated capital S. Try this:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"]
```

Note that the `NSDate` you get back is `2016-01-27 17:28:53.344 +0000`. This is due to `NSDate` always represent time in UTC. `17:38 UTC` is the same moment in time as `18:38 +01:00`.